# How do you use the "Alternate Forms For Complex Commands" in zsh

Tags: shell, loops, zsh

[This resource](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Alternate-Forms-For-Complex-Commands) lists alternate versions of `ìf`, `for`, `while` and a few others. I'm confused as to how they can be used and where they should be used.

Could someone provide an example usage for each?

> if list sublist
>
> > A short form of the alternate ‘if’. The same limitations on the form of list apply as for the previous form.
>
> for name ... ( word ... ) sublist
>
> > A short form of for.
>
> for name ... [ in word ... ] term sublist
>
> > where term is at least one newline or ;. Another short form of for.
>
> for (( [expr1] ; [expr2] ; [expr3] )) sublist
>
> > A short form of the arithmetic for command.
>
> foreach name ... ( word ... ) list end
>
> > Another form of for.
>
> while list { list }
>
> > An alternative form of while. Note the limitations on the form of list mentioned above.
>
> until list { list }
>
> > An alternative form of until. Note the limitations on the form of list mentioned above.
>
> repeat word sublist
>
> > This is a short form of repeat.
>
> case word { [ [(] pattern [ | pattern ] ... ) list (;;|;&|;|) ] ... }
>
> > An alternative form of case.
>
> select name [ in word term ] sublist
>
> > where term is at least one newline or ;. A short form of select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The misleading terminology being used for the syntax of these alternate forms took a while to decipher, but using a bit of trial and error I have come up with some answers to what ZSH allows you to use.

The following lines all produce:

```
1
2
3
```

### for

```
for i ("1" "2" "3") echo $i
for i ("1" "2" "3") { echo $i }

for i in ("1" "2" "3"); echo $i
for i in ("1" "2" "3"); do echo $i

for i in "1" "2" "3"; do echo $i; done
for i in "1" "2" "3"; { echo $i }

for (( i=1; i<4; i++ )) { echo $i }
for (( i=1; i<4; i++ )); do echo $i; done
```

### foreach

```
foreach i ("1" "2" "3") { echo $i }
foreach i ("1" "2" "3"); do echo $i; done
```

### until

```
i=1; until (( i > 3 )) { echo $((i++)) }
```

### while

```
i=0; while (( i < 3 )) { echo $((++i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for the `if` statement:

```
foo=5
if (( foo == 5 )) echo yay
```

The documentation states that the sublist (here, `echo yay`) must be of the form `{ ... }` so that it can be distinguished from the sublists comprising the previous `list`; however, it appears that as long as it is obvious where the separation is (here, you cannot have a list containing two sublists separated by non-newline whitespace), that requirement can be relaxed.

The documentation also states that they should not be used where any portability is desired; they are essentially provided for interactive use for short commands. Intuitively, you can imagine that they apply to commands that fit on one line.

Here are the relevant paragraphs:

> Many of zsh's complex commands have alternate forms.  These are non-standard and are likely not to  be  obvious
>          even  to  seasoned shell programmers; they should not be used anywhere that portability of shell code is a concern.
>
> The short versions below only work if sublist is of the form '{ list }' or if the SHORT_LOOPS  option  is  set. For  the  if,  while  and  until  commands, in both these cases the test part of the loop must also be suitably delimited, such as by '[[ ... ]]' or '(( ... ))', else the end of the test will not  be  recognized.   For  the
>    for, repeat, case and select commands no such special form for the arguments is necessary, but the other condition (the special form of sublist or use of the SHORT_LOOPS option) still applies.

Comment: I understand the `if` one, but not the usage for `foreach` and `select`. Could you provide an example of these?